# How to call component after component initialization in angular 2

Tags: angular

Is there a way to initialize a component after other component finish it's initialization?

My case is I have a fullcalendar and when  finish it's initialization, a new component needs to start initialization, because he needs data from the calendar. So is it possible to catch when the initialization of the 1st component finishes in order to start the initialization of the 2nd component?

At the moment the two components are starting together and I am encountering the problem if 2nd component finishes first, it is not showing the information which needs to be taken from the 1st component

primary component html :

```
<app-calendar-component [view]="calView" [callback]="calendarOptions" >
</app-calendar-component>
<app-weekdetails-component></app-weekdetails-component>
```

fullcalendar component(1st component which needs to be initialized):

```
ngOnInit(){
this.service.getTimes<any>(arg).subscribe((data:string)=> this.result = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => () => {
            console.log("error");
        },
        () => {
//data actions
this.my_events.events = dataArray;
            this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.my_events);
}
}
```

weekDetailsComponent (2nd component):

calling here another service which is getting the data  which is included in every single day, this component needs to start it's initialization after fullcalendar finishes.

Comment: Can you share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

TS :

```
showCalendar:boolean = false;
ngOnInit(){
this.service.getTimes<any>(arg).subscribe((data:string)=> this.result = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => () => {
            console.log("error");
        },
        () => {
//data actions
this.my_events.events = dataArray;
            this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.my_events);
            this.showCalendar = true;
}
}
```

HTML :

```
<app-calendar-component [view]="calView" [callback]="calendarOptions" >
</app-calendar-component>
<app-weekdetails-component *ngIf="showCalendar"></app-weekdetails-component>
```

{{showCalendar}}

Comment: Well it is not showing the second component. I think problem comes from that the primary component calls the initialization of the calendar component and 2nd component at the same time, so the value of the showCalendar is still false, so that's why it is showing only the first component. Of course when initiliazation of the calendar finishes, it is changing the value of the showCalendar but the 2nd component doesnt show

Comment: Try printing the value of `{{showCalendar}}`, does it reflect on view?

Comment: as value of `showCalendar` will be false `app-weekdetails-component` will not be initialised in DOM.

Comment: the result is false

Comment: That should be `true`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a private boolean property initialized as false for Example `private isInit: boolean = false;`. In the callback you set this property as true in the calendar callback. 
In your html you have to add to your second component `*ngIf=“isInit”`.

Hope it can help